# Filter items in a view, without affecting number of items in pager

Tags: views, 8

I want to filter items in my view:

```
<?php

function permissions_by_term_views_pre_execute(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  $view->query->addWhere(
    0,
    db_like()
      ->condition('nid', 9, 'NOT IN')
  );

  return $view;
}
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function condition() on a non-object in
>   /mnt/c/Users/peter/Dev/pbt-d8/modules/permissions_by_term/permissions_by_term.module
>   on line 95

I have flushed the cache. How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Would `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` work for you?

Comment: No no, I want to do it on the backend side.